# How to get a direct link to a public file I store on OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

On my PC I routinely drop files into OneDrive via the Windows Explorer.
How do I get a link to the file without having to go to the website and sharing it publicly?

Example. I drop file foobar.txt into the public folder and want to send a friend the link to this file. For instance http://onedrive.live.com/myuserid/public/foobar.txt. When I click on the link, it should simply download the file, not go to a webpage that lets you download it.

Dropbox provides something like this. You can drop the file into your public folder and then access it as https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/{userid}/foobar.txt

Does OneDrive provide such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

> **Onedrive** 
>   1. Right click the file, for which you want to create download URL, then select share. 
>   2. Then, click on 'Get a link'. 
>   3. Under 'Choose an option' select 'Public'. Click on 'Create link'. Now, you will be given a link. Use that to create direct link.

Source: http://www.syncwithtech.org/2014/09/direct-download-link.html

Comment: That is the point - I don't want to do that for every file (in hundreds) I drop into that folder.  It would take way long.  I want a predictable URL that I can generate based on the file name.. e.g. http://onedrive.live.com/myuserid/public/FileIjustDropped.docx

Comment: Unfortunately, OneDrive does not currently have that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to access files directly in the public folder. Although as default you still must create a share link and access the file via the share link first. There may be a sharepoint setting I am unare of that prevents the need for this.

Use:
https://{ms-business-acc}.sharepoint.com/sites/{company} Public/Shared%20Documents/{folder-names-and/or-file-names}

Ensure you replace a space with "%20" as this is a web link.

When you create a share link for a file or folder the first part of this link is created.
https://{ms-business-acc}.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/{company}Public/**EueXs0zsw-tJmpDnOJmZLwgBagyP7OUFzHeYOGcTZt8QIA?e=zw49nH**
Remove the section in bold.

If you add the tag "&download=1" at the end of your URL it will link directly to the file and not show inside a Sharepoint/OneDrive splash screen.

Useful REF: https://sharepointmaven.com/the-anatomy-of-a-sharepoint-url/